# Arduino bug when "myFile = SD.open" is inside loop()

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, spi

My Arduino resets / bugs each time I put `myFile = SD.open` in `loop()`.

In `setup()` it works fine.

I have a 20*4 LCD and an RTC connected to I2C, an SD card reader connected to SPI, and a fingerprint sensor.

Here is my code:

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <DS3231.h>;

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3f,20,4);
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);
Sd2Card card;
SdVolume volume;
SdFile root;

int etat = 0;
int getFingerprintIDez();
const int chipSelect = 10;
SDFile myFile;

void setup() {
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  rtc.begin();
  finger.begin(57600);
  SD.begin();

  // Reglage Heure 
  //rtc.setDOW(TUESDAY); // Set Day-of-Week to SUNDAY
  //rtc.setTime(10, 57, 0); // Set the time to 12:00:00 (24hr format)
  //rtc.setDate(24, 11, 2016);   // Set the date to January 1st, 2014
  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Capteur Initialise");
  } else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Capteur Deconnecte");
  }
  delay(2000);
  if (SD.exists("data.csv")) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("data.csv OK.");
    delay (1000);
  } else {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Creating data.csv...");
    myFile = SD.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
    myFile.close();
    delay (1000);
  }
}

void loop() {
  if (etat == 0) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Put Finger");
    getFingerprintIDez();
  }
  if  (etat == 1) {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("ID #");
    lcd.setCursor(4,0);
    lcd.print(finger.fingerID);
//  myFile = SD.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
//  myFile.print(rtc.getDateStr(1));
//  myFile.print("\t");
//  myFile.print(rtc.getTimeStr(1));
//  myFile.print("\t");
//  myFile.println(finger.fingerID);
//  myFile.close();
    lcd.setCursor(0,2);
    lcd.print("Loged");
    etat = 0;
  }
  delay(1000);
}

int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Found ID #");
  lcd.setCursor(14,0);
  lcd.print(finger.fingerID);
  etat = 1;
  return finger.fingerID; 
  delay(1000);
}
```

Each time I uncomment lines using SD, the Arduino resets at the end of the loop.

What is the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't repeatedly open the file, even if you close it in between.  Both the nature of flash based storage and the limitations of object oriented techniques in an Arduino's tight memory mean you should avoid unecessary operations like that.  Also you should check the validity of the file object before you try to do operations on it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to extend your 2 states machine in a multiple states machine.

Declare the `enum eState` before `setup()`:

```
typedef enum e_State {
    STATE_START = 0,    // starting the loop (add some initialisation)
    STATE_READ_FINGER,  // Step1: read the finger print
    STATE_DISP_FINGER,  // Step2: display the finger print
    STATE_OPEN_LOGGER,  // Step3: open the log file
    STATE_WRITE_LINE,   // Step4: append a timestamp finger print
    STATE_CLOSE_LOGGER  // Step5: close the log file
} eState;
```

And update the `loop()` function with the state-machine:

```
void loop()
{
    static eState LoopState = STATE_START; // to store the current state

    eState NextState;  // for the next loop

    switch (LoopState) {
    case STATE_START:
        // add additional settings
        NextState = STATE_READ_FINGER;
        break;
    case STATE_READ_FINGER:
        etat = 0; // keep use your 'etat'
        // or return a boolean from your 'getFingerprintIDez()'
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("Put Finger");
        getFingerprintIDez();
        if (etat == 1) {
            NextState = STATE_DISP_FINGER;
        }
        break;
    case STATE_DISP_FINGER:
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print("ID #");
        lcd.setCursor(4,0);
        lcd.print(finger.fingerID);
        NextState = STATE_OPEN_LOGGER;
        break;
    case STATE_OPEN_LOGGER:
        myFile = SD.open("data.csv", FILE_WRITE);
        if (myFile) {
            // record only if file is opened
            NextState = STATE_WRITE_LINE;
        }
        else {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("Can't open file");
        }
        break;
    case STATE_WRITE_LINE:
        myFile.print(rtc.getDateStr(1));
        myFile.print("\t");
        myFile.print(rtc.getTimeStr(1));
        myFile.print("\t");
        myFile.println(finger.fingerID);
        myFile.flush();
        NextState = STATE_CLOSE_LOGGER;
        break;
    case STATE_CLOSE_LOGGER:
        myFile.close();
        lcd.setCursor(0,2);
        lcd.print("Loged");
        NextState = STATE_READ_FINGER;
        etat = 0;
        break;
    default:
        NextState = STATE_START;
    }
    // next loop()
    LoopState = NextState;
    delay(200);
}
```